# Attribute Error on trying to retrieve image to python docx from Database

Tags: python, sqlite, python-docx

I'm trying to get text and images stored in database onto a word doc with python docx, the text is retrieved fine, on trying to retrieve images I get the following error. AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'. Code is below.

```
import sqlite3
from docx import Document

document = Document()
name = "The heading of the report"
document.add_heading(name,0)

connection = sqlite3.connect("demo.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Users where UserID = 1")
images in binary format
data = cursor.fetchall()
for row in data:
    zero = row[0]
    one = row[1]
    two = row[2]

document.add_paragraph(str(zero))            
document.add_paragraph(str(one))
document.add_picture(two)

document.save('UserReport.docx')
connection.close()
```

The dB Table structure for easy testing is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserID  integer,
    UserName text NOT NULL,
    UserImage Blob,
    PRIMARY KEY(`UserID`)
);
```

I can see the error is generated because of this line, document.add_picture(two). But don't understand the cause, would appreciate your inputs on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `picture` argument to `.add_picture()` needs to be a file-like object. Try it this way:

```
from StringIO import StringIO  # would be from io import BytesIO in Python3 
image_stream = StringIO(two)
document.add_picture(image_stream)
```